# Why is DataGridViewRowCollection.DataGridView property protected?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

The choice of protection level for `DataGridView` property of `DataGridViewRowCollection` is something I cannot comprehend. It is set to `protected` so one cannot acces it from outside which would be a natural thing to do. I can't imagine anyone giving reasonable explanation for this, but maybe... anyone?

Comment: Because in normal usage you shouldn't have to access the DataGridView from the row, because you will already have a reference to it. However, is you're implementing a custom DataGridViewRowCollection (if such a thing is even possible) then you would need to able to access the parent.

Comment: Well in fact the very same property in `DataGridViewRow` is `public`. A more natural way of extending `DataGridViewRowCollection` would be by using extension methods since even if I extended it by inheritance, there is no way I could replace the `Rows` property of `DataGridView`. So inheritance makes sense if I'm implementing a completely new control, but why would I use `DataGridViewRowCollection` in that case instead of my own collection?

Answer (score 0):

I believe stuartd is right about that it is to encourage extending `DataGridViewRowCollection` by inheritance, not by extension methods. I found it strange since I thought there is no way of replacing `DataGridView`'s `Rows` property with your own implementation. It turns out there is a way to accomplish that and it is called `protected void CreateRowsInstance()` – a method of `DataGridView`, so it seems at least a little reasonable to put the `DataGridView` property in the protected scope.